# How to add LocalSocket to Selector in Android?

Tags: java, android, localsocket

I am creating a local socket like this:

```
LocalSocket sock = new LocalSocket();
sock.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("my-abstract-name"));
Selector sel = Selector.open();
```

How to add LocalSocket sock to Selector sel?